How to Generate Unique IDs for Chat Messages in Laravel with GridDB?
I'm building a real-time chat application using Laravel and want to use GridDB as my database due to its high performance with time-series data. Since GridDB doesn't have an official PHP client, I've set up a custom integration using a middleware API in Python that communicates with GridDB. My Laravel application interacts with this middleware via HTTP requests.
In my chat application, each message needs a unique ID. In traditional relational databases like MySQL, I would use an auto-incrementing integer as the primary key. Since GridDB doesn't support auto-incrementing IDs natively, I need a reliable way to generate unique IDs for chat messages that can handle high concurrency since multiple users might send messages simultaneously.
I tried combining the current timestamp with a random number:
$messageId = time() . mt_rand(1000, 9999);

This reduces the chance of collisions but isn't foolproof, especially under high load.
I attempted to simulate auto-increment by querying the maximum existing ID and incrementing it:
$maxId = $this->getMaxMessageIdFromGridDB();
$messageId = $maxId + 1;

However, this approach isn't safe in a concurrent environment and can lead to race conditions.
Would using GridDB's TIMESTAMP row key with sub-second precision be a viable option for unique IDs?

Using GridDB for a chat app looks very weird to me...

I presume you're after a UUID. I don't know anything about GridDB but it feels weird to choose it because of its high performance and then use it through a Python API. GridDB has a web API, you don't really need Python here anyway.


Would using GridDB's TIMESTAMP row key with sub-second precision be a viable option for unique IDs?

No. Still has collision risks.
While you could build some sort of sequence generator you might want to have a look at uniqid(). This is still not completely safe. If you plan to run this at scale, you might want to add in a host and/or client enumeration.
Depending on where you intend running this you might want to setup an entropy gethering daemon.
